# See the STDOUT redirect of a running process

Tags: shell, io-redirection, open-files

If I start an app with this command:

```
/path/to/my/command >> /var/log/command.log
```

And the command doesn't return, is there a way, from another prompt, to see what the STDOUT redirect is set to?

I'm looking for something like either

```
cat /proc/PID/redirects
```

or

```
ps -??? | grep PID
```

but any method will do.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Check out the file descriptor #1 (STDOUT) in `/proc/$PID/fd/`. The kernel represents this file as symbolic link to a file the descriptor is redirected to.

```
$ readlink -f /proc/20361/fd/1
/tmp/file
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Can you provide a link or details about the other redirects such as STDERR, ie which numbers they are?

Comment: At least on Linux (and I believe on every other known UNIX-like OS) they are 0: stdin, 1: stdout, 2: stderr (standard error). Note there are also C macros defined in <stdio.h>: STD{IN,OUT,ERR}_FILENO. See 'man stdout' for details.

Comment: 0, 1, 2 for stdin, stdout and stderr respectively are guaranteed in all Unix/Unix-like systems, and are also true on Windows.

Comment: on MacOS any way to do this? the /proc/<pid>/fd/1 does not exist, maybe I can use mkfifo?

Answer (score 12):

A lot of answers mention doing it this way:

```
tail -f /proc/{PID}/fd/1
```

However, I've found that it doesn't always work. Alternatively, the `cat` sometimes yields results.

```
cat /proc/{PID}/fd/1
```

where {PID} can be looked up using the `ps aux` command.

Also good to mention, is that the number on the end of the command (in this case fd/1) can be changed for other outputs.

```
 /proc/{PID}/fd/0 # STDIN
 /proc/{PID}/fd/1 # STDOUT
 /proc/{PID}/fd/2 # STDERR
```

Answer (score 9):

A useful tool to see what files are opened by what processes is [`lsof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof). You can point it at a specific process with `lsof -p1234`, and you'll see mostly the same information as you can get with `ls -l /proc/1234/fd` under Linux, i.e. what files are opened.

The most useful thing with `lsof` is going the other way round: `lsof /path/to/file` tells you what processes are using that file.